# Naming convention for top directory of git clone?

Tags: git

I have set up my remote repositories on a server with the naming convention of using the suffix `.git`, e.g.

```
some_proj.git
```

When I clone such a repository, the default name of the directory created is

```
some_proj
```

I then rename this local repository to `some_proj.git`. because I want to be reminded that the directory is under version control (I should probably choose a different suffix which doesn't conflict with that for the remote).

My question is:

Is it really necessary to indicate whether a local directory is under version control by means of a naming convention?

My thinking is that, although my prompt is set up to indicate the git status of the current working directory, if I do, say, a `find` from outside a git repository, I won't be able to see which of the results are under version control and which aren't.

Is that a valid point or am I suffering from some sort of wrongheadedness?

Comment: Voted to close as "primarily opinion-based". If there are any differences at all, they only relate to your personal workflow. Since it's your local repository on your local machine, it doesn't even affect others. So I can't think of a fact-based answer other than "Name it however you want to as long as it works for you".

Comment: I see your point but I am exactly interested in whether there is some fact I am overlooking.  To me it seems almost essential that I would want to be able to determine whether a file is under version control just by looking at the path.  Maybe my use-case of both developing and deploying on the same machine is unusual.

Comment: For what it's worth, `.git` is considered to be used for bare repositories (i.e., ones without a working copy) only. This does not keep you from naming it `.vc` or whatever you would want it to name.

Comment: I would say that what you do with your local repo is up to you. You could add a `.THISISAGITREPOSITORY` suffix, and no one but yourself would be able to tell (unless you allow other users to log in to your machine). Personally, I have one `repos` directory, and all the repos I clone, I clone in that directory. That way I know that anything under that dir will be a repo.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the .git suffix when naming your remotes, stuff like that can only cause problems. It should be obvious that your local repo is under git as it will contain a .git folder. If you use a tool like Tortoise git under Windows, then when you use Windows Explorer your local git controlled folders and files will all have overlay icons to show that they're under git source control. Keep everything as simple as humanly possible.

Comment: My way of keeping things simple is using the Linux command-line, so I am not looking for something like overlay icons.  As I mentioned, my prompt will indicate when I am in a repo, but I want the information to be available easily **outside** the repo.